# Creating firewall rule for current IP with AzureCLI on AzureDevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I'm running my db migrations from a deploy script on AzureDevOps, and I'm using AzureCLI to create and remove a firewall rule:

`az sql server firewall-rule create -g rg --server server --name ADO-Deploy --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 255.255.255.255`

`az sql server firewall-rule delete -g rg --server server --name ADO-Deploy`

This works fine, but it seems a bit excessive to open up for every single IP.

Is there a way to tell Azure to open up only for the current IP?
Or any other convenient way of getting my public ip in the deploy script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different services to determine your external ip and use the result

```
ip=$(curl ipinfo.io/ip)
az sql server firewall-rule create -g rg --server server --name ADO-Deploy --start-ip-address $ip --end-ip-address $ip
```

something like that